# Why CKEditor wont add html in my databse with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor and Laravel, but when I try to put a text in bold or color, Laravel won't insert it in my database, can you help me to solve this ?

Here is my controller :

```
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|string|min:5|max:256',
            'body' => 'required|string|min:5|max:500000',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            flash('Une erreur est survenue lors de la publication')->error();
            return Redirect::route('siac_store_release');
        }

        $release = new Release;

        $release->title = $request->title;
        $release->body = $request->body;

        $release->save();

        flash('Le communiqué a bien été publié.')->success();
        return Redirect::route('siac_releases');
    }
```

I can give more infos if it's necessary.

Sorry for my english, that's not my first language.

Comment: The problem is on your blade code

Comment: when printing the POST data array, do you receive the content in an HTML format or just a regular text??

Answer (score 0):

Use CKEditor configuration file config.js with [allowedContent](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules.html) property set to `true`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {    
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```